# Why not calling window procedure instead of calling CallWindowProc?

Tags: windows, winapi, callback, function-pointers

Why is there such function CallWindowProc? We are supplying the address of the window procedure, so isn't it better to call the function instead of calling another function which calls the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `GetWindowLong` (or `GetWindowLongPtr`) might return a value that is not a function pointer, which `CallWindowProc` can recognise and translate into a proper call. [[1]](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=oldnewthing&y=2003&m=12&d=01&WeblogPostID=55900&GroupKeys=)

Comment: If there is something strange in Windows API, you can bet it comes from compatibility with old versions.

Answer (score 1):

The CallWindowProc function handles Unicode-to-ANSI conversion. You cannot take advantage of this conversion if you call the window procedure directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Could I ask why `CallWindowProc` has a unicode/ansi problem? There is no TCHAR parameters in its signature.

Comment: @ChenOT I guess it's that the LPARAM of various types of message often point to strings -- either narrow or wide strings depending on how the Window procedure was created.